# Single Status Letter for the Netherlands

Tags: visa, immigration, netherlands

I may be relocating to the Netherlands and would like to take my unmarried partner with me. Part of the process is proving that we are both single. My state doesn't issue single status letters, so we'll have to go the affidavit route. You can get one from the consulate,  but it's pretty expensive ($50).

Is it acceptable to recreate [the affidavit that we could get at the consulate](https://photos.state.gov/libraries/netherlands/383034/acs_affidavits/AFFIDAVIT%20of%20Civil%20Status%20new%20date.pdf) (removing references to the consulate) and have it notarized and apostilled ($10) in the US instead?

Comment: I would suggest calling the US embassy in the Netherlands to ask this question.  In case the Netherlands official receiving your document has any question about the document, they are likely to call the same place.

Answer (score 1):

The consular route actually costs $50 plus €10 [for the legalization](https://www.nederlandwereldwijd.nl/wonen-werken/buitenlandse-documenten-legaliseren/legaliseren-van-documenten-van-ambassades-en-consulaten-in-nederland).

The [page on document legalization for US citizens in the Netherlands](https://www.netherlandsandyou.nl/your-country-and-the-netherlands/united-states/travel-and-residence/legalising-your-documents) says this about these affidavits:

> Certificate of unmarried status
>
> You can prove your unmarried status with an affidavit. An affidavit is a written declaration that you make under oath in the presence of a notary. The notary confirms your signature.
>
> If you are in the Netherlands, you can obtain an affidavit at the US Consulate-General in Amsterdam. You must be a US national. The consul will confirm your signature. You will then need to have the affidavit legalised by the Consular Service Centre in The Hague.

The last paragraph certainly implies that if you are *not* in the Netherlands, you can use an affidavit obtained elsewhere.  As long as your affidavit is valid under the law of the state where it was sworn and also meets Dutch requirements (less than six months old, with apostille), then it seems they will accept it.

Comment: That's how I read it as well. I'm glad you agree!

Comment: I can now confirm that this is correct having successfully received both visas.